# Order by nested objects date

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a chat application and have the following models representing the chat room, chat message and the counter of unread messages

```
class ChatRoom(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField('accounts.User', related_name='chat_rooms')

class ChatMessage(BaseModel):
    text = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')

class ChatRoomUnreadMessagesCounter(BaseModel):
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='unread_counters')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    messages_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I would like to make an API view that would return a list of `ChatRoom` objects that are ordered in the following manner: `ChatRoom` objects that have unread messages ordered by messages count -> `ChatRoom` objects that have messages in them by the latest message `created_at` last in first out -> `ChatRoom` objects that are sorted alphabetically. How would I construct my queryset properly?

Here's an expected result output

```
| Room Name | Unread Messages | Last Message          |
| Rean      | 2               | 09.11.2021T12:00:00   |
| Ash       | 1               | 09.11.2021T12:00:24   |
| Altina    | 0               | 09.11.2021T12:15:00   |
| Juna      | 0               | 09.11.2021T12:14:00   |
| Kurt      | 0               | 09.11.2021T12:13:00   |
| Musse     | 0               | 09.11.2021T12:12:00   |
| Sharon    | 0               | No messages yet       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really trivial. Hope someone gets a simpler answer. Mine includes [SubQuery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

```py
    from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

    # get query which references an 'id' field of the parent qs
    latest_message_subq = Subquery(Message.objects.filter(
        room=OuterRef("id")).order_by("-created_at").values('created_at')[:1]
    )

    # annotate the unread count per room
    # assumes there's only a single counter per owner
    unread_count_subq = Subquery(ChatRoomUnreadMessagesCounter.objects.filter(
        room=OuterRef("id"), owner=user).values('messages_count')[:1]
    )

    # Room.objects.all() is the parent qs
    # So the OuterRef("id") is pointing to a room id
    rooms = Room.objects.annotate(
        latest_message_time=latest_message_subq,
        unread_count= unread_count_subq
    )
    # every object in the rooms qs should now have the attributes latest_message_time and unread_count; you can loop it to verify

    rooms = rooms.order_by('-unread_count', '-latest_message', 'name')
```

EDIT: Changed to get a Room qs at the end

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. What I need is a list of `ChatRoom`s, not the counters though.

Comment: No worries. The `values_list` returns exactly what's in your expected result. I'll turn the answer around to get a Room Queryset in a sec.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a spin as soon as I can

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with an actual queryset and not valuest_list by the way? I'm using django rest framework and I'd lose out on its default pagination and filter backend if I transform the queryset

Comment: ah nevermind, the `rooms` is the actual queryset, I'm blind

Comment: I edited the answer, so you get a queryset at the end which will act as if the room model has the `unread_count` and `latest_message` fields. So filtering, ordering and other qs operations over those 2 fields should work and every object in the qs should have them as attributes.

Comment: Getting this error now `This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`, trying to figure it out

Comment: Does `.first()` evaluate the queryset? That might be the problem here since we're trying to use it in a subquery

Comment: I've just updated it. You're right :)

Comment: SubQuery does need to evaluate into a QS

Comment: yeah I just replaced .first with [:1] and it worked, just need to test this now. The problem I'm seeing is that there is no timestamp returned for the latest message

Comment: actually nevermind that, I haven't included it into the serializer yet, will test and write back

Comment: For every object in the room qs, you get the `created_at` of the latest message, so that should be the timestamp :)

Comment: Here's another problem. The rooms that have no messages in them are being returned first, since their `latest_message_time` is null, any way for me to make the nulls come in last?

Comment: Figured it out `qs = rooms.order_by('-unread_count', F('latest_message_time').desc(nulls_last=True), 'name')`